# ios storyboard: How to switch 2 views in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a question regarding the structure of a navigation controller that has to manage 2 views.

I have a navigation controller. 
At some point, it displays geographical data, that can be displayed either in a map or in a table view.
I would like to stay in my navigation controller, and be able to have a switch to display either the map or the tableview ViewController.

Currently, I have the following:

```
    -NavigationController
       .parentViewController
       .mapViewController
       .tableViewController
```

I have a segue from parentVC to mapVC, one from mapVC to tableVC (tabbar button). If I create one from tableVC to mapVC (tabbar button also), it does not work anymore as it creates a loop.

I know I could switch views programmatically, but I would like to keep my views editable in the storyboard screen (I don't want one view on top of the other in the screen)
Is there a way to have a clean structure using storyboards, that keeps views editable in the storyboard?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

It is not reccommended to have 2 views in one view controller. Rather, make 2 nearly identical view controller, one for the table view and one for the map. Unsure if that is what you have, and then from one of the view controllers do:

```
[self presentViewController:tableVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
[self presentViewController:mapVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```